# How can I catch any 'not defined' route with Silex

Tags: silex

I have defined several routes in Silex, but I don't know how to catch not existing routes.

For example:

```
$app->get('/category/{name}', 'Acme\Controller\Main::category');
```

I expect it is not necessary to defines all routes ad infinitum:

```
$app->get('/category/{name}', 'Acme\Controller\Main::notFound');
$app->get('/category/{name}/', 'Acme\Controller\Main::notFound');
$app->get('/category/{name}/{name2}', 'Acme\Controller\Main::notFound');
$app->get('/category/{name}/{name2}/', 'Acme\Controller\Main::notFound');
$app->get('/category/{name}/{name2}/{name3}', 'Acme\Controller\Main::notFound');
[...]
```

What is the most elegant solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can catch all errors using `$app->error()` - see also [Silex Documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#error-handlers).

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {

  if ($app['debug']) {
    // in debug mode we want to get the regular error message
    return;
  }

  switch ($code) {
    case 404:
        $message = 'The requested page could not be found.';
        break;
    default:
        $message = 'We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.';
  }

  return new Response($message);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And could I send an HTTP 404 Error for that and render also a twig template?

Comment: [Silex ensures that the Response status code is set to the most appropriate one depending on the exception](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#error-handlers), so there is no need to set an error code here. The documentation also describe who to override the current status code setting an `X-Status-Code`. 
And shure: you can also render a template and return it - I'm using this too [in my applications](https://github.com/phpManufaktur/kfBasic/blob/master/bootstrap.include.php#L750).